# How make recycler view with multiple datasets?

Tags: android, arrays, android-recyclerview, recyclerview-layout

I'm trying to make recyclerview from html table rows.

I've made adapter and recycler_item layout.

```
public class RecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder> {

private String[] mDataset;  


// класс view holder-а с помощью которого мы получаем ссылку на каждый элемент
// отдельного пункта списка
public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder  implements View.OnClickListener{
    // наш пункт состоит только из одного TextView
    public LinearLayout Item;
    public TextView mTextView;
    public TextView mTextView1;
    public TextView mTextView2;
    public LinearLayout mLabel;
    private Context context;

    public ViewHolder(View v) {
        super(v);
        mTextView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv_recycler_item);
        mTextView1 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv_recycler_item2);
        mTextView2 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv_recycler_item3);
     //   mLabel = (LinearLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.extended);
        Item = (LinearLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.Item);

        context = v.getContext();
        v.setClickable(true);
        v.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, ExtendedActivity.class);

        context.startActivity(intent);


    }
}


// Конструктор
public RecyclerAdapter(String[] dataset) {
    mDataset = dataset;
}

// Создает новые views (вызывается layout manager-ом)
@Override
public RecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent,
                                                     int viewType) {
    // create a new view
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.recycler_maket, parent, false);

    // тут можно программно менять атрибуты лэйаута (size, margins, paddings и др.)

    ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder(v);
    return vh;
}

// Заменяет контент отдельного view (вызывается layout manager-ом)
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    holder.mTextView.setText(mDataset[position]);   


}

// Возвращает размер данных (вызывается layout manager-ом)
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mDataset.length;
}
```

In main activity there is a cycle, which parse html doc, and writes elementid text to array.

```
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
 //   return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fragment_task, container, false);
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fragment_task, container, false);
    String[] myDataset = getDataSet();
   mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.my_recycler_view);

    // если мы уверены, что изменения в контенте не изменят размер layout-а RecyclerView
    // передаем параметр true - это увеличивает производительность
    mRecyclerView.addItemDecoration(new VerticalItemDecoration(VERTICAL_ITEM_SPACE));
    //or
    mRecyclerView.addItemDecoration(
            new DividerItemDecoration(getActivity()));
    //or
    mRecyclerView.addItemDecoration(
            new DividerItemDecoration(getActivity(), R.drawable.line_divider));
    // используем linear layout manager
    mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
    // создаем адаптер
    mAdapter = new RecyclerAdapter(myDataset);
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    return rootView;
}
private String[] getDataSet() {
    String[] mDataSet = new String[];
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        mDataSet[i] = "parsedhtmldata" + i;
    }
    return mDataSet;
}
```

So this array will be text for textview in recyclerview.

This is able to do recyclerview with one element in.

 So how to do the same, but with additional textviews in one recyclerview item?

Comment: As per the code you are already using more than one textview in recyclerview item but only setting data to single textview. Let me know if I misunderstood your question.

Comment: @Jickson Right! You undersood well. In adapter i set three textview, but in cycle it is only one dataset. I have no idea how to do all 3 textviews in cycles at mainactivity. Yes, I know, my english is awful)

Comment: I have explained you one possible solution in my answer. Hope it helps. Let me know if you need any clarification.

Comment: @Jickson so how will be look like onCreateView method?

Comment: Just change "String[] myDataset = getDataSet();" to "DataSet[] myDataset = getDataSet();".

Comment: @Jickson incopatible types. required java.lang.String[], found DataSet[]

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106920/discussion-between-jickson-and-alex).

Comment: Have you updated getDataSet function ??

Comment: Solved it - placed DataSet class into fragment too. But there is new problem -  mAdapter = new RecyclerAdapter(myDataset); - RecyclerAdapter(packacge.RecyclerAdapterDataSet[]) in RecyclerAdapter cant be applied to package.fragments.MyFragment.DataSet[]

Comment: Do not create multiple DataSet class

Comment: Where should I place it? in fragment or in Adapter?

Comment: place it in fragment

Comment: Then in adapter all about dataset makes red underline

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a class like

```
static class DataSet {
    String field1;
    String field2;
    String field3;
}
```

Then make changes to Adapter like below

```
public class RecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder> {

private DataSet[] mDataset;


// класс view holder-а с помощью которого мы получаем ссылку на каждый элемент
// отдельного пункта списка
public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
    // наш пункт состоит только из одного TextView
    public LinearLayout Item;
    public TextView mTextView;
    public TextView mTextView1;
    public TextView mTextView2;
    public LinearLayout mLabel;
    private Context context;

    public ViewHolder(View v) {
        super(v);
        mTextView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv_recycler_item);
        mTextView1 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv_recycler_item2);
        mTextView2 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv_recycler_item3);
        //   mLabel = (LinearLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.extended);
        Item = (LinearLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.Item);

        context = v.getContext();
        v.setClickable(true);
        v.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, ExtendedActivity.class);

        context.startActivity(intent);


    }
}


// Конструктор
public RecyclerAdapter(DataSet[] dataset) {
    mDataset = dataset;
}

// Создает новые views (вызывается layout manager-ом)
@Override
public RecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent,
                                                     int viewType) {
    // create a new view
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.recycler_maket, parent, false);

    // тут можно программно менять атрибуты лэйаута (size, margins, paddings и др.)

    ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder(v);
    return vh;
}

// Заменяет контент отдельного view (вызывается layout manager-ом)
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    holder.mTextView.setText(mDataset[position].field1);
    holder.mTextView1.setText(mDataset[position].field2);
    holder.mTextView2.setText(mDataset[position].field3);
}

// Возвращает размер данных (вызывается layout manager-ом)
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mDataset.length;
}
}
```

Then change method in fragment

```
private DataSet[] getDataSet() {
    DataSet[] mDataSet = new DataSet[100];
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
        dataSet.field1 = "parsedhtmldata 1" + i;
        dataSet.field2 = "parsedhtmldata 2" + i;
        dataSet.field3 = "parsedhtmldata 3" + i;
        mDataSet[i] = dataSet;
    }
    return mDataSet;
}
```

Comment: 10x a lot! I will try this 2night!